# Hide caption in wrapfigure

Tags: latex

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{one}
  \end{center}
  \caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

How can I hide label 'Figure 1:' below inserted image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \caption{} adds the label. You can omit it and get rid of 'Figure 1:'

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, I have found solution.  Just remove \caption{} line.